# How to add a mean line for grouped data plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, plyr

im using a loop to plot histograms of monthly air quality data, which grouped by year using the `facet_grid()` function. in my plots i have a mean line of mean of the month of all years, and i would like it to be the mean by month per year.

my code is:

```
for (z in vec) {
  
  df.g <- pol %>% filter(poluentes==z)
  df.g$year <- as.character(df.g$year)
  df.g$month<- as.character(df.g$month)
  
  mu <- ddply(df.g, "month", summarise, grp.mean=mean(value)) # mean line 
  
  print(ggplot(df.g, aes(x=value, fill=month, color=month)) +
          geom_histogram(position="identity", alpha=0.2) +
          labs(title=z,x="µg/m3", caption = "Análise: poluente") + 
          geom_vline(data=mu, aes(xintercept=grp.mean, color=month),
                     linetype="dashed") + facet_grid(year ~.))
  
}
```

the output is:

and as you can see, the mean line is the same for the 3 histograms

[image]

Comment: Your `mean(value)` statement is using the whole dataset. Can you add a  `group_by(year)' statement before the `summarise()`?

Comment: You need to supply mean values for each year in a df that can be split in the faceting call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculations of means need to include the year as well:

```
set.seed(111)

df.g = data.frame(year = sample(18:20,1000,replace=TRUE),
month = factor(sample(3:4,1000,replace=TRUE)),
value = rnbinom(1000,mu=50,size=1))

mu = aggregate(df.g$value,list(month=df.g$month,year=df.g$year),mean)
```

Then pass it:

```
ggplot(df.g,aes(x=value,fill=month,col=month)) +
geom_histogram(bins=20,position="identity", alpha=0.2) + 
facet_grid(year ~ .) +
geom_vline(data = mu,aes(xintercept = x,col=month))
```

[image]